# Ubuntu 20.04: cannot shutdown properly, failing to start services

Tags: shutdown, bug-reporting

My Ubuntu 20.04 system somehow doesn't work properly anymore. Shutting it down doesn't work anymore neither do network or sound services.

Using `sudo shutdown` via terminal freeze the terminal, shutting it down via the GUI let it hang on this screen infinitely:
[image]

During starting several services i.a. network and sound services fail to start.
Output from `journalctl -b -p err`:

[image]

I am sorry for the pictures instead of text.

My system:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic
        Linux 5.4.0-56-generic (I tried it with both)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3900X 12-Core
GPU: RTX 2080 Ti
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "recovery" mode to allow your system clean start & shutdown?
While "off"

1. Power on your system & watch for the manufacturer's logo on the screen.
2. Immediately press "Esc" which will take you to the "recovery Mode.
3. Scroll down to the latest version of Linux Kernel (first on top).
4. Select each option begin from top. (clean, file check, autoremove, etc)
   Once done restart & shut down. If problem still insist.
5. repeat 1 @ 2. This time select the older Linux kernel & repeat the same.

Hopefully by this time your system should work fine.

Comment: I have two kernel versions available, I tried them both in recovery. I checked all available options. Both times it didn't change the issues.

Comment: As much as undesired -- you may have to clean reinstall your OS. Just make sure to backup your "Home" Directory (I use deja' Dup Backup) to restore files & settings.